# Create a $Near group in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection with a set of geo-points that will be printed on a Map. 
I want to group all the points that are nearby by 30 meters, and return all the points but grouped.

How I could make this query?
Thanks!

My collection has documents like this:

```
{
"_id" : NumberLong("26130948889"),
"segment" : {
    "name" : "A Fake Name",
    "category" : 3
    "location" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [
            41.16364669799805,
            -3.0703139305114746
        ]
    },
    "other-relevant-data" : 9.199999809265137
},
"elapsedTime" : NumberLong(2016)}
```

and want something like this:

```
{[
"_id" : NumberLong("26405224704")
"segment" : {
    "name" : "Fake Name 1",
    "category" : 2,
    "location" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [
            40.785404205322266,
            -3.9882829189300537
        ]
    },
    "other-relevant-data" : 11.899999618530273
},
"elapsedTime" : NumberLong(1265)},{
"_id" : NumberLong("26405224730"),
"segment" : {
    "name" : "Fake Name 2",
    "Category" : 5, 
    "end" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [
            40.78533935546875,
            -3.987668037414551
        ]
    },
    "other-relevant-data" : 7.300000190734863
},
"elapsedTime" : NumberLong(4557)}],[{
"_id" : NumberLong("26130948889"),
"segment" : {
    "name" : "A Fake Name",
    "category" : 3
    "location" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [
            41.16364669799805,
            -3.0703139305114746
        ]
    },
    "other-relevant-data" : 9.199999809265137
},
"elapsedTime" : NumberLong(2016)}]
```

Comment: What have you tried? Because odly enough a simple search like https://www.google.com/search?q=mongodb+group+by+near strangely lists both the required operators in the official documentation as the top 2 results. Kind of odd really. Maybe you should actually try implementing what the search seems to suggest you actually do.

Comment: Hi!
I make a lot of google search before post here. In the official doc, you need to provide "coordinates: [ <longitude> , <latitude> ]". I don't want to provide this, I want to group the other documents.

Comment: Really? Then how come there is absolutely no attempt at writing such a query in your question? Nor is there any mention at all of said operators? If you actually put some effort into this as you claim, then you should at least have part of the solution and might only be asking how to solve the other part. But your question shows no evidence of this. Do you actually have a code attempt to share?

Comment: And also such details as "providing coordinates" are therefore **cruicial** to anyone understanding what you are asking. So if you do not actually want to "query" for something and you just expect the "database to work it out for itself", then how would you propose that actually happens? What is supposed to be the "distance"? From what exactly? From each point? Relative to which other point(s) exactly? Are these just points or Polygons? Asking a question here should not raise that many questions in response. It is completely unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Ok, I assume that my question ins unclear.

Comment: Maybe you should do something about that then. But also consider what you are asking. If it was even remotely possible then you would need to have been able to do something that at least came "close" to a result. The basics of what you are asking just has too many possible outcomes. I think really you should try to narrow down your case to something that has a remote chance of being reproducible.

Comment: I solve the problem in the front app. then, close the question. 
I need to clear my ideas before posting here...